# COPY AND Paste values based on if criteria

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to find a way to copy and paste values based on a criteria in excel, and was wondering what the best method would be.

Sheet 1
Column A has the months 1,2,3
Column B has the sales data for month

Sheet 2
Reporting Month in A1

My formula or code needs to copy and paste values the data for each cell in column B on sheet 1, if the month in column A on sheet 1 is less than the value in A1 on sheet 2.

Need your expertise as i'm not very good with excel or vba.

cheers in advance

Comment: "*My formula or code needs to copy and paste values*" - Great! Let's see it and maybe we can help you with your **existing** code

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for Advanced Filter. On the data tab, in the Sort & Filter section there is an Advanced link. Use the Copy to another location feature to do your copy/paste. There is lots of information on the internet about using advanced filter and creating criteria.

Helpful Hint: Created a named range for your source data set, it will be easier to run the filter.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to paste values over the existing data